# Dealing with "Duplicate identifiers" when Reshaping Data from Long to Wide Format with Tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, tidyr

I can't seem to figure out how to get around the tidyr `spread` error

> "Error:Duplicate Identifiers"

First, I'll use the simple dataframe below to show how I would like the results to look. The dataframe below works the way I would like since there are no duplicate identifiers.

```
Names<-c("John","John","John","Chris","Chris","Chris","Sara","Sara","Sara")

Category<-c("Accommodation","Disability","Living Arrangements","Accommodation","Disability","Living Arrangements","Accommodation","Disability","Living Arrangements")

Description<-c("Apartment","Vision","Alone","House","SCI","Family","Alone","Vision","Spouse")

df<-data.frame(Names,Category,Description)
```

I then use tidyr's `spread` to create a wide-format dataframe:

```
dfS<-df%>%spread(Category,Description)
```

This produces a dataframe with "Category" as the column variables filled in with "Description.

However, the data I'm actually working with resembles the dataframe below and when I attempt to create the same tidy dataframe using tidyr's `spread` as above, I get the "duplicate identifier" error since the equipment category has two options.

```
Names<-c("John","John","John","John","John","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Chris","Sara","Sara","Sara","Sara","Sara")

Category<-c("Accommodation","Disability","Equipment","Equipment","Living Arrangements","Accommodation","Disability","Equipment","Equipment","Living Arrangements","Accommodation","Disability","Equipment","Equipment","Living Arrangements")

Description<-c("Apartment","Vision","Scooter","Walker","Alone","House","SCI","Walker","Bed","Family","Alone","Vision","Cane","Bed","Spouse")

df<-data.frame(Names,Category,Description)
```

I can't quite figure out a simple way to deal with this situation. I've checked other posts on here and most are too complex or don't work. I tried this option:

```
df2<-df%>%group_by(Category,Description)%>%
     summarise(Category=toString(unique(Category)))%>%
     spread(Category,Description,fill='')
```

but it results in a

> "Error: Cannot modify grouping variable"

I copied the code from another post, so I admit I'm not sure entirely how it works and may have made a mistake. I'm still relatively new to R and especially tidyr so I'm hoping someone can provide a simple solution that will allow me to create the tidy dataframe using tidyr's spread in the first example above, preferably with the help of dplyr or reshape2.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "deal with". You know you have duplicate rows... how do you want them handled? If you load library(reshape2), then `dcast(df, Names ~ Category, fun=toString)` is an option. There may be a way to do that with tidyr.

Comment: I think your solution will work if you use it on the right variables.  I believe you want to group by Names and Category and then summarize Description via `toString`.

Comment: Thanks Frank, the "fun=toString" command is what I was looking for and couldn't figure out in Tidyr. One question now, when I use the dcast formula, how do I fill in the blank cells with NA? I imported the data with NA's, but when I use: dcast(df, Names ~ Category, fun=toString), the NA's disappear and there are blank cells.